# Defining a fourth level domain in Bind9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm setting up an internal application on my LAN which requires several fourth level DNS domains. The third level is the hostname itself. What is the correct way to define these in Bind9? Do I define the fourth level domains right alongside the third level hostname, or is it best to create an `$ORIGIN` and define the fourth levels there?  Going off some documentation here: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/origin.html in which the examples don't show (that I can see) how `uk.example.com` is resolved.

The hostname for the appserver is `zodiac.froblan.net`. Other domains needed are:

```
 assets.zodiac.froblan.net
   smtp.zodiac.froblan.net
noreply.zodiac.froblan.net
```

My bind configuration file `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` contains this:

```
...
       zone "froblan.net" in {
               type master;
               file "internal.db.froblan";
        };
...
```

The zone file `/var/cache/bin/internal.db.froblan` contains this:

```
$TTL    300
...
mike                 IN A 10.10.10.100
ike                  IN A 10.10.10.101

; is this correct? I need DNS for zodiac.froblan.net so...
zodiac.froblan.net   IN A 10.10.10.102
...

;..do fourth levels then go under an $ORIGIN like this?
$ORIGIN zodiac.froblan.net.
assets   IN A 10.10.10.103
smtp     IN A 10.10.10.104
noreply  IN A 10.10.10.105
...
```

This setup seems to work, but not sure it's not breaking any RFCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right to me, though I would check your `zodiac.froblan.net` entry to make sure it isn't actually creating `zodiac.froblan.net.froblan.net`.

In a zone file, if the hostname ends in a period, it is absolute (fully qualified), otherwise it is relative to the most recent origin.

You can also declare 4th level subdomains with multiple prefix parts without respecifying $ORIGIN like

```
assets.zodiac IN A 10.10.10.103
```

Comment: Thanks. `nslookup zodiac.froblan.net.froblan.net` errors out. Would `dig @ns1.froblan.net froblan.net axfr` show any unintentional side effects or does that just basically dump the zone file?